# Getting date of X days ago in bash script, using argument variable

Tags: bash, date, arguments

I'm trying to calculate the date for a dynamic number of days ago in a bash script.

This is what I've done -

```
#!/bin/bash
STAMP=`date --date='$1 day ago' +%y%m%d`
```

but when running `myscript 2`, it says -

```
date: invalid date `$1 day ago'
```

How can I use my argument value in this formula?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It works if ' is replaced with " into this command on the script -

```
STAMP=`date --date="$1 day ago" +%y%m%d`
```

The clue was the two different character ` and ' used in the error response -

```
date: invalid date `$1 day ago'
```

An expert in bash scripting (not me) can probably explain why this has happen.

Comment: As mentioned by @devnull below, single quotes prevent variable expansion. You can always test "what is happening behind the scenes" by adding an echo:

    echo date --date='$1 day ago'

Answer (score 13):

It's because variable substitution wouldn't happen in single quotes, i.e. `'$1'`  wouldn't expand but `"$1"` would.

As such, saying

```
STAMP=`date --date="$1 day ago" +%y%m%d`
```

or

```
STAMP=$(date --date="$1 day ago" +%y%m%d)
```

would work.